# What does Gluon SceneBuilder look for in JAR files?

Tags: javafx, clojure

Using Clojure, I'm trying to write a custom JavaFX component for use in Gluon SceneBuilder, to be loaded up from a .jar file.  That is, I'd like to point SceneBuilder to the .jar with my custom class, and have the thing show up in the list of draggable items on the left.

I can make the visual structure show up with FXML only, but I'd like to include some behavior as well.

After doing the `(:gen-class)` stuff in my Clojure source, running `lein uberjar`, and using the `fx:root` construct in the FXML, I'm able to use the resulting class in a modified version of the official Java [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm).

When I instantiate my custom class in the `CustomControlExample`, I see evidence of the Clojure init code running (via printlns and other stuff in the graphics).

So my custom class appears to work normally.  It has two constructors -- with and without a `String` argument, and extends from HBox.  I can verify these when I view the resulting `.class` file in NetBeans and also using JarExplorer.  The class has a ton more stuff in it, due to being a Clojure constructed class, but it has at least the same number and type of constructors as the example.

The problem is my custom component does not appear in the SceneBuilder when I import the uberjar file.

So the question is: What **exactly** does SceneBuilder need to see in the class to make it appear as a custom draggable component?

Here is the relevant portion of my one source file (it includes a utility library for dealing with starting up the FX runtime).

src/toyui/GridSettingsPane.clj:

```
(ns toyui.GridSettingsPane
  (:gen-class
   :extends javafx.scene.layout.HBox
   :post-init post-init
   :init init
   :constructors {[] []
                  [String] []})
  (:use [jfxutils.core :exclude [-main]]))


(defn -init
  ([]
   (-init "unnamed-init"))
  ([name]
   (println "hi from -init")
   [[] []]))

(defn -post-init
  ([this]
   (-post-init this "unnamed-post-init"))
  ([this name]
   (println "hi from -post-init")
   (jfxutils.core/app-init)
   (let [loader (javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader. (clojure.java.io/resource "GridSettingsPane.fxml"))]
     (.setRoot loader this)
     (.setController loader this)
     (.load loader)
     loader))))
```

Comment: Perhaps your component needs a width and a height.

Comment: Hm, just added `(.setWidth this 800)` and `(.setHeight this 600)` but no cigar.  I'll start digging through the SceneBuilder code to see what's up.

Comment: I found that adding `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);` to `instantiateWithFXMLLoader(...)` in JarExplorer.java seems to get past the immediate issue, but now there's an IllegalStateException "Location is not set" in the FXML loader.  Probably more classpath stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that SceneBuilder was using some real-time class loading.  Clojure defaults to `*use-context-classloader*` = `true`, so I was able to get the class to load, sort of, by modifying the scenebuilder code a little as in my comment above.  However it still was having some trouble with finding some type of resource.  I figured it was still probably due to class paths and the like.

In the process I also discovered that the SceneBuilder dynamically creates a little FXML file (stream, actually), which says, among other things, `<?import toyui.GridSettingsPane?>`, and the runs the regular FXML loader on that stream.

So I went and modified [FXMLExample](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) to import my Clojure class from within the .fxml file and it worked.

So the conclusion is yes, my class will work as-is in the FXML when running from a regular program, but for some reason doesn't load up when the jar explorer is looking.